# Deploy 3rd party Apps via Microsoft Deployment ToolKit

Tags: windows-7, java, microsoft-office-2010, symantec, unattended

I want to deploy an image containing Windows 7 x64, Office 2010 Professional Plus x86, Java, Adobe Reader and Flash player and SEP Client. 
I've made successfully an image containing Windows 7 x64, Office 2010 Professional Plus x86. But I don't know that how to add 3rd party apps such as Java, Adobe Reader and Flash player and SEP Client.

Is there a way of using MDT 2010 to do this? if so ,please clarify.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add Office to the original image there is nothing that stops you from adding more applications the same time.
Applications that supports unattended install (such as office) can be added as an optional application in MDT though, which makes it possible to select during installation.
Personally I prefer to install 3rd party applications through GPO though, since that makes it simple to upgrade existing computers without wiping them (which pretty much MDT requires).
Of course, if you have SCCM (System Center Configuration Manager), that gives you a much better management experience! With 30+ computers to manage I would consider installing that!

Comment: Well What are the quiet commands for adobe reader,flash player,java,SEP? is there any link related to this?

Answer (score 0):

MSI files are by far the easiest to install via MDT as there is no guessing. Installsheild installers can be scripted with ISS files, and the generic standalone executable will require some guesswork.

The real trick is knowing the commandline syntax that is necessary to install the file. Again, MSI is the easiest as the syntax is as follows:

```
msiexec.exe /qb- /l*vx %LogPath%\file.log REBOOT=ReallySuppress UILevel=67 ALLUSERS=2 /I filename.msi
```

[image: Add Application]

[image: Syntax]